# Finding the range of paramter space in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I have a function depends on for example 2 parameters f[a,b], and I know the value of this function should range between 300 < f < 400, how I know the possible ranges of the parameters 
in Mathematica.

S.S.

Comment: You might get an answer faster if you post this question on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

That may depend on the specific function.  Can you post it?

There is no general answer to your question.  The output of a function may be range bound regardless of the input parameters.  For example, this Lissajous function never exceeds -1 < x < 1

```
f[a_, b_] := ParametricPlot[{Sin[a/b t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi b}]

f[1, 2]

f[9, 10]
```